Connecting renovate to a private gitlab
I have installed renovate through npm. I am trying to connect it to my private gitab repository, but i keep getting authentication errors.
I have set RENOVATE_SSL_KEY, RENOVATE_ENDPOINT, RENOVATE_TOKEN, RENOVATE_SSL_CERT.
In the Authentication error, i can see some redirection is happening, but i cant make out much beyond that.
Error:
"message": "external-host-error",
         "stack": "Error: external-host-error\n    at GitlabHttp.request (/home/.nvm/versions/node/v20.13.1/lib/node_modules/renovate/lib/util/http/gitlab.ts:82:15)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at GitlabHttp.requestJson
FATAL: Authentication failure
 INFO: Renovate is exiting with a non-zero code due to the following logged errors
       DEBUG: GET https://gitlab.myrepo.com/user = (code=ERR_BODY_PARSE_FAILURE, statusCode=200 retryCount=0, duration=195)
 WARN: Retry-After: unexpected status code 200
       "url": "https://myrepo.cloudflareaccess.com/test/access/login/gitlab.myrepo.com?kid=df67c81e77f936b99757efc9e2afabd12b849b67aa6389703d7ae20a61de9fe5&redirect_url=%2Fuser&meta=eyJraWQiOiI3NmFkOWEwZDg0YzNhMDFhMmRhNGRlYzgyNzQ2NzliMGJjMDRhNjc3MWFjY2FjOTUxNmY0MzIwMTljOTA2YTZiIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3Rva2VuX3N0YXR1cyI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTcxOTUwNDI4NSwic2VydmljZV90b2tlbl9pZCI6IiIsImF1ZCI6ImRmNjdjODFlNzdmOTM2Yjk5NzU3ZWZjOWUyYWZhYmQxMmI4NDliNjdhYTYzODk3MDNkN2FlMjBhN"  
DEBUG: Gitlab API error  
       "err": {  
         "name": "ParseError",  
         "code": "ERR_BODY_PARSE_FAILURE",
          "message": "Unexpected token '<', \"<!DOCTYPE \"... is not valid JSON in "https://myrepo.cloudflareaccess.com/test/access/login/gitlab.myrepo.com?kid=df67c81e77f936b99757efc9e2afabd12b849b67aa6389703d7ae20a61de9fe5&redirect_url=%2Fuser&meta=eyJraWQiOiI3NmFkOWEwZDg0YzNhMDFhMmRhNGRlYzgyNzQ2NzliMGJjMDRhNjc3MWFjY2FjOTUxNmY0MzIwMTljOTA2YTZiIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3Rva2VuX3N0YXR1cyI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTcxOTUwNDI4NSwic2VydmljZV90b2tlbl9pZCI6IiIsImF1ZCI6ImRmNjdjODFlNzdmOTM2Yjk5NzU3ZWZjOWUyYWZhYmQxMmI4NDliNjdhYTYzODk3MDNkN2FlMjBhN"
          "stack": "RequestError: Unexpected token '<', \"<!DOCTYPE \"... is not valid JSON in 
           "message": "Unexpected token '<', \"<!DOCTYPE \"... is not valid JSON in "https://myrepo.cloudflareaccess.com/test/access/login/gitlab.myrepo.com?kid=df67c81e77f936b99757efc9e2afabd12b849b67aa6389703d7ae20a61de9fe5&redirect_url=%2Fuser&meta=eyJraWQiOiI3NmFkOWEwZDg0YzNhMDFhMmRhNGRlYzgyNzQ2NzliMGJjMDRhNjc3MWFjY2FjOTUxNmY0MzIwMTljOTA2YTZiIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJzZXJ2aWNlX3Rva2VuX3N0YXR1cyI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTcxOTUwNDI4NSwic2VydmljZV90b2tlbl9pZCI6IiIsImF1ZCI6ImRmNjdjODFlNzdmOTM2Yjk5NzU3ZWZjOWUyYWZhYmQxMmI4NDliNjdhYTYzODk3MDNkN2FlMjBhN"

Any help would be appreciated

How did you configure Renovate? What value did you use for RENOVATE_ENDPOINT? How do you usually access your gitlab repo?
